# Best practice for automated backups of Ghost content?

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I'm setting up my first Ghost blog right now and trying to figure out: what is the best way to routinely backup my content using an automated script?

I see many posts online about [how to manually backup the contents](https://www.allaboutghost.com/how-to-backup-your-ghost-blog/), and [some scripts](https://cataldohosting.com/ghost-blog-backup-script-for-ubuntu-14-04/) [to do this](http://www.devopsfu.com/2014/07/15/backup-azure-webjob/). However, they all involve stopping the Node/Ghost processes while running a script to backup the database. Is there any way to do an automated backup without stopping Ghost?

Comment: Hi Jordan, I've been using AWS for a while and have found the EBS volume backups - even manual perfect for this use case.

I'm also wondering if perhaps the best solution going forward is to have load-balanced Ghost instances that point to the same database. If ghost could connect to an external database with multiple ghosts behind an ELB all other instances (bar one) could have read-only access. We could shutdown the write Ghost instance prior to backing up. Need to investigate this though.

Obviously an external database source is a blocker here...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, right now you cannot automate the backup without shutting down Ghost. This is because it isn't smart to be copying the database while it could be being read/written to. A script that stops Ghost, makes a copy, and starts it back up would prob only ~1 second of down time, so if you have times that are slower, you could probably get away with it. If you can't, then just do the manual export for all the post data, and have a script backup all your images.